# Simulating an 'Insert' button click-event in asp.net listview control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview

One of my webpages has an asp.net ListView control, with an insertitem template defined.  I would like to allow the users of the page to enter data in a text field in the insertitem template, press the enter key, and trigger the insert event (which normally happens when you click the 'insert' button).  Can someone please tell me what I need to do for this?  I've tried simulating the button click event in javascript, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the button with CSS(display:none) and the on the ENTER make jQuery press it.

Answer (score 0):

The new(asp.net 3.5) [defaultbutton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) attribute can be used with  or  control. What button will be "clicked" depends of where actually cursor is and what button is chosen as a default button for form or a panel.

```
<form defaultbutton="button1" runat="server">
<asp:textbox id="textbox1" runat="server"/>
<asp:textbox id="textbox2" runat="server"/>
<asp:button id="button1" text="Button1" runat="server"/>

<asp:panel defaultbutton="button2" runat="server">
    <asp:textbox id="textbox3" runat="server"/>
    <asp:button id="button2" runat="server"/>
</asp:panel>
</form>
```

You could use it to trigger your defaultbutton(insert) when you place the controls in InsertItemtemplate inside of a Panel.

Comment: Tim, I tried it using the panel method, and it didn't seem to work.